# Static IP in ubuntu server 15.10

Tags: networking, server, 15.10, dns

I know there's a lot of this kind of questions and tutorials about setting static ips, but I've tried everything and still I can't manage to get a static ip. Internet's working fine (I can ping google.com), but I'm not getting the ip I want, I'm still getting a random ip (usually 192.168.1.8)

Here's my config:

```
auto lo
auto lo intet loopback

auto lo enp2s0
iface lo inet loopback
iface enp0s3 inet static
        address 192.168.0.107
        netmask 255.255.255.0i
        gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 200.45.191.35 200.45.48.233
```

This is what I get when I put *ifconfig -a*:

```
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:70:f4:3f:8c:c5  
          inet addr:192.168.1.8  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba70:f4ff:fe3f:8cc5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:380 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:363 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:1
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:34659 (34.6 KB)  TX bytes:63438 (63.4 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:354 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:354 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:59253 (59.2 KB)  TX bytes:59253 (59.2 KB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 38:59:f9:c5:4d:5b  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

And this is *route*:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp2s0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.2        *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp2s0
```

And this is my *less /etc/resolv.conf*

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 200.45.191.35
nameserver 200.45.48.233
search Home
/etc/resolv.conf (END)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check your `netmask 255.255.255.0i` ?

Comment: Your interface is `enp2s0`. You are addressing  `enp0s3`

Comment: @EdiD Thank you, I modified both things, rebooted but I still can't get the ip I want (192.168.1.107), I'm getting 192.168.1.8

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using the correct interface name, and correcting the netmask line, as suggested in comments, your file also lists the `address` field as 192.168.0.107 instead of 192.168.1.107.

You also need to remove these two lines:

```
auto lo enp2s0
iface lo inet loopback
```

And replace them with:

```
auto enp2s0
```

So your whole `/etc/network/interfaces` file should look like this:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
 address 192.168.1.107
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 192.168.1.1
 dns-nameservers 200.45.191.35 200.45.48.233
```

Rather than rebooting you can restart your interface with:

```
ifdown enp2s0 && enp2s0
```

Comment: Now it gets the ip I want. Now when I want to ssh, "ssh 192.168.1.107" is not working, but "ssh 192.168.1.8" works, which is really weird. I wanted the static ip mostly for ssh.

Comment: Check whether you can ping the new address. `ping 192.168.0.107`

Comment: Now something even weirder is happening. I can access from 192.168.1.8 and 192.168.1.107, and yes I can ping 192.168.1.107

Answer (score 2):

Change in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo enp2s0
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp2s0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.107
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 200.45.191.35 200.45.48.233
```